# No value in form - AngularJS POST

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do a post of a form in angular, but the input **testValue** doesn't get a value.

Any suggestions?

**In the angularJs controller:**

```
//FORM
$scope.submitEditSyncSettingsForm = function () {
    if ($("#editSyncSettingsForm").valid()) {

        $http({
            url: "data/postSyncSettings.aspx",
            data: { testValue: 'some value' },
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' } 
        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }).error(function (err) { "ERR", console.log(err) })

    }
};
```

**.aspx code behind**

```
public partial class postSyncSettings : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string strResponse = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        strResponse = Request.Form["testValue"];
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ($("#editSyncSettingsForm").valid()) {` - Angular has `$invalid` properties for forms with specified attributes - should avoid mixing jQuery and Angular (just a tip, no answer to the question at hand)

Comment: okay, thanks. how would I write it instead?

Comment: Don't mix AngularJS and JQuery! Never!
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/3006185

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Comment: Could you provide your server-side part of example?

Comment: Still off topic, but tried `if ($scope.editSyncSettingsForm.$valid) {` and get the error message: TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined. The form looks like this `<form id="editSyncSettingsForm" class="form-grouped" ng-submit="submitEditSyncSettingsForm()" default-validate>`. Please not that I am using jQuery validation because I am writing an app for a system based on jQuery which has built in validation. So the `default-validate` directive is actually initiating that validation.

Comment: @ArtyomPranovich I updated the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the data is still sent in the body as JSON. You'll have to serialize it yourself. You can use the `serializeData()` function from [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm)...

```
$scope.submitEditSyncSettingsForm = function () {
    $http({
        url: "data/postSyncSettings.aspx",
        data: serializeData({ testValue: 'some value' }),
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }).error(function (err) {
        "ERR", console.log(err)
    })
};

// http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm
function serializeData(data) {
    // If this is not an object, defer to native stringification.
    if (!angular.isObject(data)) {
        return ((data == null) ? "" : data.toString());
    }

    var buffer = [];

    // Serialize each key in the object.
    for (var name in data) {
        if (!data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            continue;
        }

        var value = data[name];

        buffer.push(
        encodeURIComponent(name) +
            "=" + encodeURIComponent((value == null) ? "" : value));

    }

    // Serialize the buffer and clean it up for transportation.
    var source = buffer.join("&")
        .replace(/%20/g, "+");

    return (source);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I would like to put it in a separate service, which was the case in the article you referred to, but I didn't get it to work. Any ideas how to do that? I am quite new to AngularJS.

Comment: What problems are you having with it? Can you create a jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: I created a new post for this where I pute the current code. Greatful for any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545033/move-function-to-factory

Answer (score 0):

1) The data passed on the server should be converted to a URL-encoded string

It can be do it with the following code:

```
$.param($scope.formData)
```

2) For form posting you should use the `ng-sumbit` directive and for validation you can use `$invalid/$valid` form's property.

```
$scope.processForm = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '...your URL...',
            data: $.param($scope.formData),  // pass in data as strings
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.Status == "Success") {
                //...
            } else {
                //...
            }
        });
    };

<form name="myForm" ng-submit="processForm()">
......

<input type="submit" value="Send Text" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
```